# How to read the Data cell by cell and output in a textbox

Tags: c#, excel

So I have this code to read my excel data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace text_extract
{
    internal class Excel
    {

        string path = "";
        _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb;
        Worksheet ws;



        public Excel(string path, int Sheet)
        {
            this.path = path;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            ws = wb.Worksheets[Sheet];
        }

        public string ReadCell(int i, int j)
        {
            i++;
            j++;
            if (ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                return ws.Cells[i, j].Value2;
            else
                return "";
        }
    }
}
```

However, `ReadCell()` only returns the first line of data and does nothing after that. How can I use a button named: Next, to print out the next line of code?

Comment: Your code doesn't really do anything. Neither the constructor nor `ReadCell()` ever gets called. What are you expecting this code to do? I also removed the Selenium tag since there's no references in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the `i++` and `j++` lines are basically useless for your purpose. When you call `ReadCell(1, 1)`, it returns the value at row 2, column 2. If you want ReadCell to always get 1 row lower than the last time it was called, you would have to store the row number used somehow. One option would be to make a global row variable.

Try something like this

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace text_extract
{
   internal class Excel
   {
      string path = "";
      _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
      Workbook wb;
      Worksheet ws;
      int currentRow = 0; 

      public Excel(string path, int Sheet)
      {
         this.path = path;
         wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
         ws = wb.Worksheets[Sheet];
      }

      public string ReadNextCell(int column)
      {
         currentRow++;

         if (ws.Cells[currentRow, column].Value2 != null)
             return ws.Cells[currentRow, column].Value2;
         else
             return "";
      }
      
      // If you did it this way, you would probably want a way 
      // to set the currentRow variable as well like this:
      public void SetCurrentRow(int row)
      {
         currentRow = row;
      }
   }
}
```